# Ajax form submit and validate within container div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

[------ Hey guys thanks for all of your help but this issue has been resolved ------]

If what I'm attempting is next to impossible please let me know guys.

Okay so I'm expected to create a tabable form and the tabs must dynamically load the link path into the specified container div. Now that's the easy part.

Okay so I have my tabable navigation and the forms load okay but when I try to validate  those forms they jump from out of the container region and unto an entirely new page. Now what I would like is for the forms to be loaded into the specified div and be validate within that div and when the submit/send button is pressed, I would like that form to connect to the php send script and upon a successful submission I want a success message to be displayed within the same specified div. So basically I want everything to behave as if they were being contained by an iframe.

Please I am begging someone to help me. I have tried and tried, but nothing works: this is my code:

html markup:

```
<section id="form-tab-block">

    <div id="form-menu-wrapper">

        <div id="form-tab-menu">
            <a class="menu_top" href="form/form_one.html">Form one</a>
    <a class="menu_top" href="form/form.html">Form two</a>
    <a class="menu_top" href="form/form.html">Form three</a>
    <a class="menu_top" href="contactform/index.php" Onclick="return                       false;">Form four</a>
        </div>

        <div id="content_area"></div>

    </div>

</section>
```

nav js script:

```
$('.menu_top').click(function() {

var href= $(this).attr('href');
$('#content_area').hide().load(href).slideDown('slow');

return false;
});



$(function() {
$('a').click(function(e) {

    // you usually want to prevent default for handling link clicks,

    // otherwise the browser follows the href (if that's intended skip this)

    //e.preventDefault();

    $('a').not(this).removeClass('Nav_Current');

    $(this).addClass('Nav_Current');

});

});
```

this is my form:

```
<?php
//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
}

//Check to make sure that the subject field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
}

//Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$",     trim($_POST['email']))) {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

//Check to make sure comments were entered
if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
    }
}

//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'your@emailaddress.com'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject     \n\nComments:\n $comments";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Accessible PHP Contact Form with JQuery Validation</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script     src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.pack.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
// validate signup form on keyup and submit
var validator = $("#contactform").validate({
    rules: {
        contactname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        subject: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        message: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
        }
    },
    messages: {
        contactname: {
            required: "Please enter your name",
            minlength: jQuery.format("Your name needs to be at least     {0} characters")
        },
        email: {
            required: "Please enter a valid email address",
            minlength: "Please enter a valid email address"
        },
        subject: {
            required: "You need to enter a subject!",
            minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
        },
        message: {
            required: "You need to enter a message!",
            minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
        }
    },
    // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
    success: function(label) {
        label.addClass("checked");
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="contactWrapper" role="form">

    <h1 role="heading">Send us a message</h1>

    <?php if(isset($hasError)) { //If errors are found ?>
        <p class="error">Please check if you've filled all the fields with     valid information and try again. Thank you.</p>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { //If email is sent ?>
        <div class="success">
            <p><strong>Email Successfully Sent!</strong></p>
            <p>Thank you for using our contact form <strong><?php echo     $name;?></strong>! Your email was successfully sent and we 'll be in touch with you soon.    </p>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"     id="contactform">
        <div class="stage clear">
            <label for="name"><strong>Name: <em>*</em></strong></label>
            <input type="text" name="contactname" id="contactname"     value="" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true" />
        </div>

        <div class="stage clear">
            <label for="email"><strong>Email: <em>*</em></strong></label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required email" role="input" aria-required="true" />
        </div>

        <div class="stage clear">
            <label for="subject"><strong>Subject: <em>*</em></strong>    </label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value=""     class="required" role="input" aria-required="true" />
        </div>

        <div class="stage clear">
            <label for="message"><strong>Message: <em>*</em></strong>    </label>
            <textarea rows="8" name="message" id="message"     class="required" role="textbox" aria-required="true"></textarea>
        </div>

        <p class="requiredNote"><em>*</em> Denotes a required field.</p>

        <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit"     id="submitButton" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
    </form>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use an iframe?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I really want to avoid using iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems (correct me if I'm wrong). 1) Validation does not trigger, 2) After submitting the form, the entire page is refreshed, correct?

For 1 you should add an event handler. I'm not sure if you've implemented the validate plugin correctly, if it's [this one](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) I suppose you have. If you haven't, and there's a javascript error, the form will simply be posted to `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` and that's why the page is refreshed. Try this in the head of your page (strip other JavaScript away for now):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#contactform").on("submit", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("I was submitted");
        });
    });
</script>
```

After submitting, do you see the alert box? You can now try to reinsert the `validate()` code like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#contactform").validate({ ... options ... });
    });
</script>
```

As for part 2, if you want to use the `div#content_area` as an iframe, you'll need a bit more javascript. Your best option is to send the form via AJAX (the validate plugin might be able to handle that for you, [read here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)) and reinsert the return value into `div#content_area`. It would look a bit like this:

```
$("#contactform").validate({
    ...,
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax(form.prop("action"), {
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: "post",
            always: function(response) {
                $("#content_area").html(response);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out and I'm so sorry I took so long to response. I was on babysitting duty. Now as it regards to your first question - the form does validate, it just doesn't stay within the div I want it to and the as for sending the form; I believe it can be submitted but I haven't actually done that as yet, because I wanted to fix this little issue first. I also implement the fix you provided but nothing happens. Is my way of trying to do this logical? I'm not the best programmer out there, so I could probably be doing something that isn't possible in this manner.

Comment: Try to fix the obvious errors first (look in your development console): `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new v.fn.init(e,t,n)} has no method 'format'`, which points to the line that says `jQuery.format("Your name needs to be at least {0} characters")`. This should probably be `jQuery.validator.format("Your name needs to be at least {0} characters")`

Comment: Nice, could you mark the answer as accepted or if you solved the problem yourself, post a new answer with your solution for future reference to other users? Thanks!

Comment: Phortuin I haven't completely finalized it yet. I'm working on a large project so I'm doing a little bit of this and that, step by step. Sorry for the late reponse.